# What is the difference between outlook meeting and appointment?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Why are the meeting and appointment separate things where seemingly they do the same thing? What is the difference?

Answer (score 12):

The main difference is that appointments affects only your own calendar and in meetings you can invite others.

In appointments, you don't have the choice to invite others and self is automatically included. Consequently there is no option to *Send* but you finish it with *Save & Close*.

For meetings, there is the *send* option because it is intended to send to participants.

A typical use of appointment is if you want to mark our calendar out of office like [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4565-outlook-block-off-time.html#a1).

Of course if you wanted to, you could arrange a meeting involving only yourself and then it's similar as an appointment.

Comment: It's semantics really at the end of the day, but this is a pretty good summary.

Answer (score 3):

Appointment is a special type of meeting where you are the only participant and you will not see any send button to send this to others.
Appointment is only meant for blocking your own calendar for specific work.
While creating an appointment, if you add even a single recipient to the appointment, the appointment turns into a meeting and you will get to see the send option as well.